# fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad) Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I followed a tutorial to dockerize an existing rails application. The app is running successfully in **development** env. But when I try to run as **stating** env I'm getting the error. I have kept same config for stating and development. Here are my related files:

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  pool: 10
  timeout: 5000
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER_NAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: db
  port: 5432

staging:
  <<: *default
  pool: 10
  timeout: 5000
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER_NAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: db
  port: 5432
```

**application.yml**

```
development:
  DATABASE_USER_NAME: 'developer'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'qmwneb10PG'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'concern_box'
staging:
  DATABASE_USER_NAME: 'developer'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'qmwneb10PG'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'concern_box'
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: cb_app_container
  db:
    container_name: cb_db_container
    image: postgres:9.6
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

**docker-compose.stag.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: staging
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 80 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

**docker-compose.dev.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/concern-box
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

init.sql

```
CREATE USER developer WITH PASSWORD 'qmwneb10PG';
CREATE DATABASE concern_box;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE concern_box TO developer;
```

I'm using following commands to spin the containers `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --force-recreate` for development env and `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.stag.yml up --force-recreate` to run as staging env.

Comment: checkout database.yml
development:
  password:

Comment: @Mezbah I tried keeping and removing password from both the envs, still got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On database.yml, `development` and `staging` are loading from ENV[], you your container should have secrets loaded from Os environment

Do not forget to load you secret into the host environment, or use env_file feature from docker-compose

docker-compose.stag.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: staging
      DATABASE_USER_NAME: ${DATABASE_USER_NAME}  # <-- Add this
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}    # <-- Add this
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}            # <-- Add this
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 80 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    expose:
      - 5432    # Just to make sure app will see the port
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      DATABASE_USER_NAME: ${DATABASE_USER_NAME}  # <-- Add this
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}    # <-- Add this
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}            # <-- Add this
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/concern-box
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    expose:
      - 5432    # Just to make sure app will see the port
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

database.yml load from ENV[], not from a file `application.yml`

```
database.yml
...
staging:
  <<: *default
  pool: 10
  timeout: 5000
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER_NAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: db
  port: 5432
...

application.yml
staging:
  DATABASE_USER_NAME: 'developer'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'qmwneb10PG'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'concern_box'
```